# Trying to access attributes in div but getting [object HTMLDivElement]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xml

This is my div:

```
<div class="card" onclick="trial(this)" namedetail="Do I Wanna Know?" artistdetail="Arctic Monkeys">`
```

When I try and output it in javascript I get `[object HTMLDivElement]`. How can I get the name detail and artist detail values out?

```
function trial(identifier) {
  console.log(identifier);
  alert(identifier);
}
```

Comment: Can you include your JS please? Specifically the part where you are doing the output pleas

Comment: @Lixus i have just added it, thanks!

Comment: in console and alert, if i do identifier.namedetail, they both print out undefined @StephenS

Comment: `this` in `trial( this )` is a reference to the DOM object that represents the DIV element it is applied to. Getting `[object HTMLDivElement]` is to be expected. You need to do more than output the DOM element. Try `identifier.getAttribute( 'namedetail' );`.

Comment: @hungerstar this worked! Brilliant, thanks!

Comment: I'd also suggest using `data-namedetail` and `data-artistdetail` as inventing your own non-standard attributes may lead to other problems

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan implemented! thanks for your advice.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes, I forgot to mention `data-`, thank you.

Comment: @hungerstar you should add your comment as an answer

Answer (score 0):

`this` in `trial( this )` is a reference to the DOM object that represents the DIV element it is applied to. Getting `[object HTMLDivElement]` is to be expected. You need to do more than output the DOM element. Try `identifier.getAttribute( 'namedetail' );`

In the end I would **1)** use `data-` attributes and **2)** do not use inline event handlers. Such a solution may look like the following.

```js
var cards = document.querySelectorAll( '.card' ),
    i = 0,
    len = cards.length;

function addClickHandler( el, fn ) {
  el.addEventListener( 'click', fn );
}

function onCardClick( e ) {
  alert( this.dataset.name );
}

for ( ; i < len; i++ ) {
  addClickHandler( cards[ i ], onCardClick );
}
```

```html
<div class="card" data-name="Do I Wanna Know? 1" data-artist="Arctic Monkeys 1">Card 1</div>
<div class="card" data-name="Do I Wanna Know? 2" data-artist="Arctic Monkeys 2">Card 2</div>
<div class="card" data-name="Do I Wanna Know? 3" data-artist="Arctic Monkeys 3">Card 3</div>
```